# Как читать файлы которые создает командная строка ДОС методом help > help.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python читает кракозябры и печатает кракозябры при чтении и записи файла при чтении/записи файла в русском DOS. Вешний редактор это легко исправляет.

А вот как сделать это в самом скрипте?

`os.system('chcp 65001')` перед сохранением в файл помогает, но не всегда. И это, мне кажется, странный способ.

Comment: `open('help.txt', 'r', encoding='cp866')`

Comment: @andreymal Это хороший ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что DOS использует свою, особенную кодировку символов для записи не-латинских символов (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP866)

Python 3 использует кодировку UTF-8, Python 2 воспринимает обычную строку как массив байтов.

Соответственно, в Python 3 необходимо открывать файл, указав его кодировку:

```py
f = open('help.txt', 'r', encoding='cp866')
```

В Python 2:

```py
import codecs
f=codecs.open('help.txt','r',encoding='cp866')
```

Comment: в дополнение, сам Пайтон работат с уникодом поэтому и нужно указывать кодировку файла - для того что-бы можна было ёё корректно преобразовать.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПа действительно, сейчас поправлю ответ